# DFS installation through GCE instance startup script not working

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, dfs-replication

I'm trying to install DFS on a Windows 2012R2 instance in GCP. The instance has a startup script, and in the startup script, it does this:

```
$code = '
Write-Host "Setting up DFS Replication for Assets"
Start-Sleep 5
Add-DfsrMember -GroupName "CMS" -ComputerName $env:ComputerName
Start-Sleep 5                                         
Set-DfsrMembership -GroupName "CMS" -FolderName "Assets" -ComputerName $env:ComputerName -ContentPath "C:\web\Proof_web\Website\Assets" -ReadOnly 1 -Force
Start-Sleep 5
Add-DfsrConnection -GroupName "CMS" -SourceComputerName gcp-staging-app-1 -DestinationComputerName $env:ComputerName
dfsrdiag StaticRPC /port:49200 /Member:$env:ComputerName
Start-Sleep 5
Restart-Service "DFSR"

Start-Sleep 5

Dfsrdiag PollAD /Member:gcp-staging\$env:computername
'

echo $code

Write-Host "Running powershell to install and configure DFS"

Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList $code -verb RunAs -WorkingDirectory C:\installers
```

I can see in the serial output that all these things look to be happening. When I RDP onto the instance and run a "Get-DFSReplicationGroup", I see what I expect, BUT when I open DFS Management mmc, there's nothing there. The "Namespaces" and "Replication" headers are there, but there's nothing underneath them.

I can then take the same code, run it manually in Powershell ISE, and it all works as expected, after a service restart on the memeber and the source instance.

Somebody, please tell me what sort of idiot I am. Be gentle.

**Updates**: Gave up on the startup script approach, pretty sure it's permissions, am finding articles where MS advisors are saying that the user has to be a domain admin, which seems pretty whack. But i'm now trying to run the script from a scheduled task, and same issue, permissions. If I add the service account to delegated permissions in DFS, I get this error now; –

"Could not add the computer to the replication group. Computer: WEB-QZL Replication group: "CMS" Retrieving the COM class factory for remote component with CLSID {CEFE3B33-B60F-44FC-BFE4-D354A1CE39EE} from machine WEB-QZL.domain.local failed due to the following error: 80070005 WEB-QZL.domain.local." Why is this process so overally complicated! –

And just to clarify, if I add the svc account to domain admins in AD, it works. I don't want to have a svc account as a domain admin. Just tell me the specific permission MS! this is killing me

Comment: Isn't that just an MMC/UI thing? Aren't you supposed to right-click the Namespaces node and select what to populate it with?

Comment: Hm, well seems that is somewhat correct, in that I can right-click on "Replication" and I can see the group that I want "CMS". I can add that to the display, but I can then see that my instance still isn't in the group, which it should be, if the startup scripts have run correctly.

Comment: Gave up on the startup script approach, pretty sure it's permissions, find articles from MS saying that the user has to be a domain admin, which seems pretty whack. But i'm now trying to run the script from a scheduled task, and same issue, permissions. If I add the service account to delegated permissions in DFS, I get this error now;

Comment: "Could not add the computer to the replication group. Computer: WEB-QZL Replication group: "CMS" Retrieving the COM class factory for remote 
component with CLSID {CEFE3B33-B60F-44FC-BFE4-D354A1CE39EE} from machine WEB-QZL.domain.local failed due to the following error: 80070005 
WEB-QZL.domain.local."

Why is this process so overally complicated!

Comment: Please [edit these details into your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74953350/edit) :)

Comment: And just to clarify, if I add the svc account to domain admins in AD, it works. I don't want to have a svc account as a domain admin. Just tell me the specific permission MS! this is killing me

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - Hey Mathias, i clicked your link but it just takes me back to the edit screen for my post. There's nothing specific highlighted. Am I missing something?

Comment: That was the point - at the edit screen you can add the details to your post :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Ah, je comprende. Apologies.

Comment: FWIW, `0x80070005` is the NT status code for Access Denied - which account are you using to run the script?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - Yeah, Im pretty confident it's a permission based issue. In GCP, the account that runs the startup scripts is just a local admin, so no domain permissions. So not really anyway to do this directly in the startup script, without passing in domain admin creadentials. Going to look at doing it via a script on a scheduled task post startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spent a bit of time messing about with this now, went with a run-once scheduled task in the end, that calls the PS script, as can't get it to work on startup without passing credentials in the script which we didn't want to do, and I'm not aware if there's anyway to change the account the startup scripts run under in GCP.

So, for a domain user / service account to have the ability to do this via the script called from a scheduled task, had to give the service account permissions via GPO. The policy / right is called "Synchronize directory service data". Once this service account had that privilege, ran the scheduled task and the new member was added, directories targeted etc.

Thanks all for your help. Hope this helps someone else in the future.

All the best.